# mysql while loop Break equivalent

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What would be an equivalent of a break in a while loop for mysql?

```
  WHILE (ctr < i)
  DO ......

    SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_results WHERE result = "true");
    IF cnt > 0 THEN
      SELECT cnt;
      BREAK;
    END IF;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

got it.

```
myloop: WHILE (ctr < i)
DO 
   …

   SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_results WHERE result = "true");
   IF cnt > 0 THEN
      SELECT cnt;
      LEAVE myloop;
   END IF;
END WHILE myloop;
```

Comment: I've updated this example. To use the LEAVE statement I found you required the `myloop` label repeated on the `END WHILE` statement.

Answer (score 19):

You might be interested in a [`REPEAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repeat.html) loop:

```
REPEAT  
    SET cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_results WHERE result = "true");
UNTIL cnt > 0 
END REPEAT;
```

Comment: This should be set as the correct way. Never even heard of the `REPEAT`, just tested it, flawless. Thanks @p.campbell